# Microsoft Assembler, Why PTR doesn't work with registers (invalid use of register)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Why the following code doesn't work, I want to move the first 2 byte of eax into variable word

```
.data

variable word ? 

.code

mov eax, 010203040h 

mov variable, word ptr eax
```

Comment: If you're using the MASM SDK by --Hutch, you can use the MACRO `m2m`. It is a MACRO to make memory to memory transfers simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registers have fixed size, you can only use size specifiers on memory operands.

Use the name of the sub-register to read or write only part of it, like AX or AL instead of EAX.

```
 mov [variable], ax

 mov word ptr [variable], ax
```

You only need the 2nd form with `word ptr` if you want to be explicit, or if variable wasn't declared as a `word` and you need to override MASM's operand-size checking for memory operands.

(The square brackets are optional but generally recommended to emphasize that it's a memory operand.)